# Convert or divide array data into multiple or multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

below is my array output.
I want to divide the data into multiple arrays or into multidimensional arrays.

```
Array(
    [cuisineId] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [dishId] => Array
        (
            [0] => 90
            [1] => 525
        )

    [quantity] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
            [1] => 440
        )

)
```

So what can I do to get the below data from the above array?

```
array(
    "cuisineId" : 1,
    "dishId" : 90,
    "quantity" : 1,
    "price" : 200
)
array(
    "cuisineId" : 2,
    "dishId" : 525,
    "quantity" : 2,
    "price" : 440
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it:

```php
function extractNum($arr, $num)
{
    return array_map(fn($a) => $a[$num], $arr);
}

$arr = ['cuisineId' => [1, 2], 'dishId' => [90, 525], 'quantity' => [1, 2], 'price' => [200, 440]];
$arr0 = extractNum($arr, 0);
$arr1 = extractNum($arr, 1);

print_r($arr0);
print_r($arr1);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [cuisineId] => 1
    [dishId] => 90
    [quantity] => 1
    [price] => 200
)
Array
(
    [cuisineId] => 2
    [dishId] => 525
    [quantity] => 2
    [price] => 440
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = [
  'cuisineId' => [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  'dishId'    => [ 90, 525, 1000 ],
  'quantity'  => [ 1, 2, 100 ],
  'price'     => [ 200, 440, 1500 ]
];

$keys = array_keys($input);
$count = count($input[$keys[0]]);

$result = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  $result[] = array_combine($keys, (array_column($input, $i)));
}
```